# javascript inside a div loaded with ajax cant access functions outside the div

Tags: jquery

I have my search results loaded into a div using an AJAX function and I am trying to add pagination to the bottom of the div which calls that ame function but I keep getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: update_results is not defined
```

Here is the page: [link removed]

There is a next page link below the results

Why cant it find the function? It works fine being called outside the AJAX div

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function is created inside `document.ready()` and not at the window level. Just move it out of there underneath `<script>` and it should be OK.

Comment: it'll be OK, but it'll be leaking into the global scope.  This is generally undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `update_results` is declared inside your `document.ready()` closure, but the embedded `onclick` handler is invoked in global scope.

Any embedded handler written as a string has to be passed through `eval()` and won't be able to see any private functions declared in other closures.

Ideally to fix it you should remove the embedded handler from the HTML, and register it inside the same closure.

FWIW, it's best IMHO never to use embedded handlers.  Event registration and handling belongs in JS files, not in the HTML.

Comment: Do you mean put the function inside the page that gets loaded into the div? I cant do this because it needs to be called on page load and the div wont have been loaded yet..

Comment: Could you expand on this further please?